# PI constant is ambiguous

Tags: rust, pi, ambiguous

Consider following code:

```
fn main() {
    let i = f32::consts::PI;
}
```

With following error:

```
$ rustc --version
rustc 1.0.0 (a59de37e9 2015-05-13) (built 2015-05-14)
$ rustc -
<anon>:2:13: 2:28 error: ambiguous associated type; specify the type using the syntax `<f32 as Trait>::consts` [E0223]
<anon>:2     let i = f32::consts::PI;
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

1. Why does it complain about an "associated type"? The only type I see here is `f32`, which is not associated.
2. Why is this ambigious? I clearly specified the `f32`.
3. What is this `<f32 as Trait>::consts` syntax? I've never seen it before.
4. And, obviously, what can I do to fix this error and get my variable set to PI?

Comment: the error is surprising (and is a bug IMHO). To make the code work you can specify `std::f32::consts::PI` or add a use `std::f32`

Comment: It's working, thanks! This solves the fourth question and maybe even 1 and 2 them if it really is a bug (which it looks like)

Comment: I reported it as an issue https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/26760, so a Rust dev can look into it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow isn’t the place for compiler bugs like this has been identified as.

Comment: It's confusing, but I don't think the difference between the **module** `std::f32` and the **type** `f32` will ever disappear.

Comment: @bluss ...but can we agree that the error message could be better?

Comment: @ChrisMorgan It's not actually a bug, just bad design.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To solve the issue, add `use std::f32` or use `std::f32::consts::PI`, so that the compiler knows we're talking about the **module** `f32` here, not the **type** `f32`.

Comment: It's actually bad design if the module `f32` and type `f32` conflict **by default**, though this is even forbidden in Rust!

Answer (score 4):

> What is this `<f32 as Trait>::consts` syntax? I've never seen it before.

This is currently called "universal function call syntax" http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ufcs.html, but we're talking about not calling it that anymore, since this isn't a function... it's more of an expanded, unambiguous form.